# Positions of a moderator

Tags: discussion, moderators, moderation

On several occasions I wanted to include this question. For example, do the moderators of this site they are all active always 24 hours on 24?

Are the roles of moderators different between them (reputation, assigned role, ban, check question, spam, rude, abusive, etc.)?

Comment: When I have problems I feel that I am alone. On an ocassion I known a post edited by a teacher asking on Meta about that he was being downvoted on the main site. I tried to help upvoting his posts with my (now deleted) old account, if I remember the downvoting continued and the teacher after few days deleted his account. I don't know if was helped by the moderators or he can to contact to the site and they helped him. I remember that for me, as ordinary user, was impossible to help him.

Comment: @user759001 In Italy they say: the world is beautiful because it is various. Two years ago I also cancelled myself and came back because my love for math is bigger than haters. I help as much as I can in my skills. I don't look for grades, I don't look for recommendations, I look for a lot of empathy and understanding. If you see my profile on TeX.SE. I am one of many who try to vote positively as much as possible.

Comment: @user759001 To encourage, not to alienate anyone, and to be as homogeneous a group possibly. Obviously one has to vote positively for the efforts made...but if someone has no idea where to start this is always up to user empathy.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The organization of the moderators team is informal. There is no hierarchy and there are no assigned roles. Of course, a less experienced moderators might ask more experienced ones for advice at times. There is no separate reputation-system either; in principle, there is statistical data on our activity.

While this is not formalized, in practice there is a certain separation of tasks, which put itself in place naturally.

We have no system in place to assure complete coverage around the clock. If something catastrophic would happen, SE could step in.

Comment: For example, do you have a warning system to wake you up at night in extreme cases? From what I understand, each of you does not perform the same tasks. Thank you very much for your kindness and the answer I received. I'm waiting if there is any other answer to get a complete idea. If there aren't, I'll give you the green tick.

Comment: I do not have such a system and I doubt any other moderator has. Ultimately a moderator cannot do much anyway about extreme scenarios. If there should be a massive spam attack or something like that, it's anyway SE that must take action.

Comment: I have not understood the downvoters for my question. Boh.

Comment: @Sebastiano the ideas put forward in the question might seem unlikely or farfetched to some. Thus, they might not see why it is necessary to ask about this. However, the alarm system,  I could *almost* see me having that.

Comment: I think that the body of in the question is right, maybe should be more precise in the word reputation (if he is understanding the reputation score), and as I understand the 
metaphor *military hierarchy*: the question is if there exists a rank or different weights for the opinions or decissions for different members of the moderator team. The questions are legitimate, and it is reasonable ask about it (be curious) in the context of a human or social group.

Comment: Now I evoke a ficticious situation to illustrate to you what means the word *farfetched*: farfetched in my understanding should be a site in which that an ordinary user had the faculty to classify the moderators as trustworthy/not trustworthy depending on whether the moderators want to chat (this could be reinforce if this specific user publicy that there exist members of the moderator team that are accessible through private conversations). Is ficticious because nobody can to think that one of such sites exists in internet, my words don't seem serious.

Comment: @user759001 I agree that's also how I understood it. Some moderators are in chat; do not hesitate to talk to us.

Comment: @quid I'm not native speaker. Excuse me but the comments of the user user759001 are all corrects.

Comment: @user759001 I have deleted "*military hierarchy with the grades*".

Comment: @Sebastiano feel free to flag for moderation any of my comments if you prefer that some of these are moderated/removed, I'm agree. Best weekend!

Comment: @user759001 Your comment, IMHO, are perfects :-)...my best regards and good holidays.